# ASP.NET Web api serializing object with \n symbol

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am retrieving class instance as a response of my rest endpoint. Here is my sample class:

```
public class Sample
{
     public string SomeThing {get;set;}
}
```

and `SomeThing` field contains next string = `"SomeText \n MoreText"`

but when I call that endpoint as a result I get next:

```
{SomeThing:"SomeText \\n MoreText"}
```

I understand that webapi is automatically saving from potential injection. But I want to prevent screening of `\n` symbol. How to do it in correct way?

Comment: What about replacing all `\\n` on `\n` in result?

Comment: My object is more complex then I mentioned in question and I believe that there is a better approach using serializer settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the "\" in your string (turning it into a double-"\"), otherwise it will become a newline in the JSON source, not the JSON data.

From [IETF](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks except
>   for the characters that must be escaped: quotation mark, reverse
>   solidus, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F).

Since a newline is a control character, it must be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with "protecting you from injection" since it's just how the JSON should be serialized/deserialized.

These are the steps describing why what you're seeing is the correct behavior:

1. In your C# variable you have this:

```
"SomeText \n MoreText"
```

2. When your object is serialized you'll have this (this is just a C# string which the quotes and the backslash escaped):

```
"{\"SomeThing\":\"SomeText \\n MoreText\"}"
```

3. Once the JSON is sent to the client (a browser for example) it'll look like this :

```
// Notice the C# backslash and quotes escaping is no longer there
{"SomeThing":"SomeText \n MoreText"}
```

4. Once your JSON is deserialized (for example using JavaScript's JSON.parse) your object will look something like this:

```
var myobject = {
    SomeThing:"SomeText \n MoreText"
}
```

The `\n` is there because in step one you said you wanted a line break there so when you print the value of Something the \n is read as a line break. For example if you print `Something` in your browser's console you see this:

```
>> console.log(myobject.Something)

SomeText 
 MoreText
```

Now if you had removed the the `\\n` after step 2 then printing the json in step 3 you would've ended up with this:

```
{"SomeThing":"SomeText n MoreText"}
```

and in step 4:

```
var myobject = {
    SomeThing:"SomeText n MoreText"
}
```

and in printing the content of `myobject.SomeThing` would result in this:

```
>> console.log(myobject.Something)

SomeText n MoreText
```